Allowing certain elements in a NCM to commute
I've got a long procedure going on, which starts with an expression, and leads to an end result similar to f2**g**f2**r**d**d**e**f1**q however, some of these things will commute. If it is just f1 and f2 that don't commute with each other, how can I automaticaly move the rest of the elements to the front to get g*r*d^2*e*q*f2**f2**f1
